# Lightning data service and force:recordPreview in Winter 17'

Tags: lightning-aura-components, winter17

Is someone aware when Lightning Data Service (and especially the force:recordPreview component) will be available ?

I thought it was scheduled with Winter 17' as mentioned in this preview live and the developer guide but I don't see it in my Winter 17' sandboxes...

[Developer Preview Live – Release Readiness LIVE, Winter '17](https://www.salesforce.com/video/275866/)
[Developer Guide Lightning Winter 17'](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/lightning.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only available in Developer Preview, so you'll need a Developer org to try it.
Currently you can get one through the Winter '17 pre-release page:
https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter17.jsp

Comment: Merci ! 

Do you know when it would be available in sandboxes or they don't intend to release it before the final force:record component ?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, I guess only guys from Salesforce could answer. However, as it's only in developer preview now and given that the name is different from the final one, I wouldn't expect it before Spring '17.

Comment: force:recordPreview is a developer preview so is only available on DE orgs.

Comment: Is there any documentation on its usage or any examples? I couldn't find any.

Comment: In the Lightning Component Developer Guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service.htm

Comment: Component docs are at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service.htm

Release notes are at https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_data_service.htm

Dev guide is at https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/lightning.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Lightning Data Service is in Beta as force:recordData in Summer '17. 
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_data_service.htm?edition=&impact=

Answer (score 0):

It's available in developer edition : https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_data_service.htm